# how to handle variadic template functions as class constructor and class members

Tags: c++, stm32, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, bare-metal

I hope you are doing great.

I have a class for which I wants its constructor to take an undefined number of arguments, then I though about variadic template.

I can instantiate objects using constructor with no parameters and also with just one parameters, but when I try to use a constructor with two parameters, I get a compile time error like:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'pinBase::init(GPIO_TypeDef* const&, const long unsigned int&)' 
pinBase(const Args& ...rest){init(<----MARKS ERROR HERE--->rest...);}
```

This is how I conceived my class:

```
//pinBase.hh
class pinBase
{
  private:

    GPIO_TypeDef *_instance;

    GPIO_PIN _pin = PIN[0];
    GPIO_MODE _mode = INPUT;
    
    //these are the functions to which each individual expansion should be called
    void _init();
    void _init(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx);
    void _init(GPIO_PIN pin);
    
    //one of these two functions gets called by the constructor either with void or param of certain type
    void init(){_init();}
    template <class T>
    void init(T t){_init(t);}

 public:

    //constructor accepts void or multiple params ( ... can be empty)
    template <class ...Args>
    pinBase(const Args& ...rest){init(rest...);}
    ~pinBase();
}
```

This is my implementation file:

```
//pinBase.cpp
#include "pinBase.hh"
pinBase::~pinBase()
{
}

void pinBase::_init()
{
    uint8_t temp = 124; // I have set breakpoint here
}
void pinBase::_init(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
{
    _resetValues = *GPIOx; // I have set breakpoint here
}

void pinBase::_init(GPIO_PIN pin)
{
    _pin = pin; // I have set breakpoint here
}
```

This is main file:

```
//main.cpp
#include "stdint.h"
#include "pinBase.hh"

pinBase pin; //works perfect
pinBase otropin(GPIOA);//works perfect
pinBase andererpin(PIN_0);//works perfect

/**When commented,the program runs well 
*and gets to each of the breakpoints 
*with no problems at all.
**when uncommented, causes compile time error. 
*/
pinBase anotherpin(GPIOA, PIN_0); 

int main(void)
{
    
    while (1)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, your constructor forwards its parameters to `init()`. You define an `init()` that takes no parameters, and an overload that takes one parameter. How do you expect to call `init()` with two parameters? That's exactly what your C++ compiler is asking you? What do you expect to happen, in that case? Can you explain what, exactly, do you expect to happen if you "use a constructor with two parameters", and how do you expect that to work, exactly??

Comment: what I expect is that "init(rest...)" makes a recursive call on either "init()" or "init(T t)", for so, "init(GPIOA, PIN_0)" I expect it to make two calls on  "init(T t)" with the corresponding parameter.
Am I not right? Thanks btw.
As I understand it, I can pass whatever number(?) of arguments to the constructir and then "init(rest...)" will handle it by doing recursive calls.

Comment: @Juan_David When you wrote: `init(rest...)`, you're calling `pinBase::init` by passing all the arguments that the parameter pack has.

Answer (score 1):

You clarified that you expect a single call to `init()` for each variadic parameter.

What you are looking for is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (requires a C++17 compiler, or later):

```
template <class ...Args>
    pinBase(const Args& ...rest){ (init(rest), ...);}
```

The syntax you're using results in a ***single*** call to `init()`, with all parameters forwarded in the single function call. The parameter pack gets expanded into a single, forwarded, parameter pack.

A fold expression, on the other hand, should produce your expected result (and you should not need an `init()` overload with no parameters).

Comment: I tried this and works exactly as I expected, thanks a lot! however, the case when Im using a void constructor I.E "pinBase pin;" the corresponding _init() function is not being called.
I tried both leaving as I had it and then deleting "void init(){_init();}"
but it did not work in any case

Comment: In that case you have two options: add an overloaded, non-template constructor that takes no arguments. I am not 100% sure if this will or will not cause an overload resolution failure, but it's worth a quick try. Alternatively, `if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) { init(); }` will be sufficient.

Comment: I tried adding the overloaded constructor with no arguments and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot man, you can't imagine how much you have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is not with the constructor itself but with the method `pinBase::init`. In particular, `pinBase::init` has only 1 parameter so you cannot call it with 2 or more arguments. That is, when you wrote:

```
init(rest...)
```

In the above, you're calling `pinBase::init` by passing all the arguments that the parameter pack has. But since `init` currently only has one parameter of type `T`, it cannot be called with 2 or more arguments.

---

To **solve** this you can make `init` a variadic as well as shown below:

```
class pinBase
{
  private:

//------------vvvvvvvv------------->T is a template parameter pack
    template <class... T>
//-------------vvv----------------->t is a function parameter pack
    void init(T... t){}

 //other code here as before
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3rWr7oxYY)